# x-shockwave-flash in Linux

Tags: video, browser

What should I install to be able to view videos of type `x-shockwave-flash` in Linux?
I found something [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-flash-player-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-gutsy/)
with instructions

```
wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/curren/install_flash_player_9_linux.tar.gz
tar xvfz install_flash_player_9_linux
cd install_flash_player_9_linux
./flashplayer-installer
```

but the file is already not there and when I try to download other file I can only choose between `Windows` and `Mac OS X`.

Comment: You're best off installing something from your distribution repositories. What is your distribution?

Comment: It's `Lubuntu 10.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [flashplugin-nonfree](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree), for browser use. Some browsers eg. Chrome and Chromium, already have the flash plugin included.

It is however not clear to me from your question whether you want a flash browser plugin or something else.

Comment: Type of application `x-shockwave-flash` wasn't working in browser. Youtube video were working. But your answer helped.

Comment: @xralf: You can use the html5 setting in youtube to avoid flash. I recommend chromium, which does support html5. Also, downloading videos is not a bad idea if possible, and avoids the necessity of having to deal with flash. See youtube-dl, clive, get-flash-videos etc.